# Multiple blackberry devices configured with the same account on Exchange 2010 and BES

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, blackberry, bes

Is it possible to have three diffferent Blackberry devices each one of them configured to access to the same Exchange account (mail, calendar, contacts) via BES?

If I read an email on a BB, the message should be flagged as read on other two, if I delete or move a message on a device or if I modify/create a calendar entry, I must see the same changes on all the devices.

Now the user has 3 BB devices configured with 3 different accounts with BES and Lotus Domino.
A feature of Domino keeps the three accounts synchronized, but I did not find such a feature on Exchange  2010

**Update**: Since BB does not support multiple device accessing the same email, the only solution by now seems to create different accounts and synch them with Exchange Sync http://www.codetwo.com/exchange-folder-sync/

Comment: Excellent question, will be interested to see if anyone has an experience doing multiple BB devices with one single email Exchange accounts. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  BES stores hidden device information such as PIN in your mailbox, activating a second blackberry will override the hidden information from the first device.

Your only options would be to setup desktop syncing, in which the devices would sync, but not wirelessly.  Alternatively you could go with less features and sync via smtp, or use mailbox forwarding to sync inbound messages between the groups.  Unfortunately this will not give the features you describe in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done that I'm aware of.

Also, your question contradicts itself. You say that you want 3 BB's to access one Exchange account but then you state that you have 3 BB's with 3 different Lotus Domino accounts.

Comment: It's not a contraddition if you read also the next sentence: "A feature of Domino keeps the three accounts synchronized, but I did not find such a feature on Exchange 2010"

Comment: It's still a contradiction. On Domino you're synching 3 devices to 3 accounts and syncing the 3 accounts. In Exchange you want to sync 3 devices to 1 account, which is not the same thing as you're doing in Domino. Am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: In domino there is a feature that keeps more than one oaccount synchronized to another. Basically you "mirror" everything (messages, message status, calendar contacts). There is no such thing in Exchange without 3rd party software. For my point of view is important how to have 3 BB syncronized with the same data. If I have yo use the same account, two accounts, or 3 accounts is a matter of configuration. Now it works in Domino with 3 accts synchronized, but can be done in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because everytime when user's account activated on the BES. Device and RIm infrastructure send a new ETP.DAT attachment mail to verify the mailbox. which is having all the device information such as device imei, pin etc. if same account already activated on the other device and we tried to activate same on second new device than BES replace the all the device info into the BES configuration DataBase and activated email ID into new device, after that Mail Flow in previous device is not happening and BES delivered the data to new device on the basis of PIN basis which stored into BES databases.

Comment: Could you please edit your post for clarity?